# Hibernate a BeagleBone Black

Tags: python, sleep, beagleboneblack

I'm a student, I am a beginner with beaglebones. I have a project and in the project we have a BeagleBone Black connected to a battery and solar panels.
It will work autonomously, and the beagle will send datas by the 3G network through an 3G usb. 
What I want to do is to save as more energy as it's possible. What I thought first was to switch on hibernation or sleep mode the beaglebone. To switch on hibernate/sleep mode and then wake up the Beagle every x seconds or minutes or anything else. 
So I want to know if it's possible and if there is an OS more adapted for that use. 
I succeeded to disable the usb chipset and then to reactivate it several minutes later.

Thank you if you can help me !

Comment: I don't think it's possible to hibernate an OS and have it magically wake up later... I *think* you can do it with sleep mode, though.

Comment: try searching for `python beaglebone "sleep mode"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_Linux_Power_Management_User_Guide#Suspend_.26_Resume

Although I'm not sure if all of this was properly mainlined, so it would need to be tested on a current image. I *might* do that later today and amend this.

This will still leave you with waking up the BBB. You'll have to see what's the best option for that. Maybe the PMIC has a suitable input for that.

Another thing is that you should exercise extreme caution when it comes to IO connections between the BBB and other components of your setup, while the BBB is off or in suspend. The SoC tends to self destruct if voltage is applied to IO pins while it's off.

Answer (score 0):

For the beaglebone black, I was able to do this using the `rtcwake` function. There are several different modes.

For instance, if you want to put the BBB in sleep mode for 10 seconds and then wake back up, you would enter the following command:
`sudo rtcwake -u 10 -m standby`

`sudo rtcwake --help` to see all options.